# android:scaleType="centerInside" not respected in androidx ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, androidx

I have two identical constraint layouts except that one is `Android X`, the other is `support`.

The Android X version does not seem to respect the scale attribute `android:scaleType="centerInside"`, as when I tilt the phone to landscape mode, the aspect ratio of the ImageView in not respected.

`support`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#252525">


    <!-- list item -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        app:srcCompat="@drawable/background_listening"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`androidx`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#252525">

    <!-- list item -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        android:background="@drawable/ic_background_unselected"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Is there any visible difference between these two layouts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In androidX remove

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

from the ImageView